# Laptop Keyboard and its cable

Tags: laptop, keyboard, cable

There is a locking part where it keeps connection cable stable. I broke it and it does not hold the cable tight anymore and keyboard does not work at all. What can I do before leaving computer to service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put little strip of photo paper and it kept the cable tight. Thickness of the photo paper helped it out successfully.